# About UV unwrapping

Tags: uv

After unwrapping and adding a checker texture, I get this issue. The retopology if the face is dense but the UVs seem like they are stretching. Whereas the retopology on the body is not very dense quite low. This is how it looks like in the uv editor: [image: uv editor screenshot]

poly still the body has a good UV and no stretch. Why is this happening?
[image: checker texture]

Comment: I think you need more - or more efficiently - placed seams. The stretch is because the head is occupying a smaller amount of UV real estate than the rest of the model. Place seams in such a way that Blender can unwrap with less stretching. That means more seams in most cases.

Comment: Okay didn't know that, I'll try it